# When I divide numbers in clojure I get a fraction , how do I get the decimal?

Tags: math, clojure, floating-point, numbers

When I do `(/ 411 125)` , I don't get it in terms of decimal. How do I do that?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
user> (float (/ 411 125))
3.288
user> (double (/ 411 125))
3.288
```

Answer (score 39):

```
user=> (clojure-version)
"1.4.0"

user=> (doc quot)
-------------------------
clojure.core/quot
([num div])
  quot[ient] of dividing numerator by denominator.
nil

user=> (quot 411 125)
3
```

Comment: doc doesn't work for me. I have the same version of clojure. Do I need to import something?

Comment: Sorry, I should've said it - it's a REPL session managed by [leiningen](http://leiningen.org). It's *the* project (and therefore dependency) management tool for Clojure projects. Once you get it going, you won't regret.

Comment: What version of lein do you use? I'm at lein 2 built from the sources.

Comment: Weird. According to [doc](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html#clojure.repl/doc) it was available in Clojure 1.0 so it should be in lein repl, too. What version of lein do you use exactly? What does lein print out when you run `doc`?

Comment: Ah, I found the problem. clojure.repl is not loaded when using slime ( I should have mentioned I am in emacs), because equivalent functions are provided differently. But can do (require 'clojure.repl) (clojure.repl/doc quot)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it has finally worked fine. Congratulations! Keep an eye on questions about doc and Clojure when slime is used - you might sort it out very easily now.

Answer (score 15):

As [documented](http://clojure.org/data_structures), integer division yields rational numbers. Try

```
(/ 411.0 125)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use a float for the dividend, you'll get a decimal answer.

```
(/ 22.0 7) -> 3.142857142857143
```

There's also the [(unchecked-remainder x y)](http://clojure.org/api) function available.

Answer (score 6):

even this will work:

```
(/ 22. 7) => 3.142857142857143
```

Comment: You should also include some explanations on why your code works and what is wrong in the original code.

Comment: nothing wrong with other solutions, but - like other solutions - i'm representing another way of thinking in doubles. as for why it's working; i'm not sure but i think clojure inherited it from java which accept any digit with decimal point as Double even if it's formatted with zero decimal position

Answer (score 2):

`(float 411/125)` is another variant if you are given the numbers directly, which is the case if you are just using the REPL as a calculator. Unfortunately this is a few characters longer than the solution by Jonathan Feinberg and ire_and_curses. ;)